# React, what is the purpose of this external HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am using sharepoint to develop and am following a tutorial, also, I am new to React.

I have an external HTML file:

```
<div id="bonus"></div>
```

And my js file:

```
var Bonus = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            greeting: 'A Message',
            thing: 'code stuff'
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div id="react-bonus">
                I am Bonus!
            </div>
        );
    }
});

$(function () {
    if (document.getElementById('bonus')) {
        React.render(
            <Bonus />,
            document.getElementById('bonus')
        );
        console.log('Bonus has shown.');
    }
});
```

When I load my site, `react-bonus` correctly shows up.  However, I noticed that when I changed my external HTML file to a completely different ID, for example: `<div id="notbonus"></div>`, I still get `react-bonus` to show, how is that possible?  What is the point of the external HTML file?

Comment: Because `react-bonus` is hardcoded its not loaded from an external file.

Comment: Was the HTML file cached when you made your change to it?

Comment: @Deckerz Ah ok, how would I show the message using the external html?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: @Enijar It is, but I refresh cache repeatedly everytime I load the web page to see if it changed or not.

Comment: @TylerSebastian I am not